# Android Scaling Density

Tags: android, scaling

I am having an issue with scaling Android across multiple screens. According to the documentation Android OS will assume your dimens.xml is created for mdpi and scale accordingly for hdpi, xhdpi, etc...

However, I am not able to see this work. If I have a folder for values-hdpi my SGS4 looks fine with the 1.5 scale ratio applied from the dimens.xml file located in the values-hdpi. However, whenever I remove the values-hdpi folder from the project to allow Android OS to scale it up to hdpi, the SGS4 just runs mdpi values. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Android Manifest:

```
    <!-- Screen Support -->
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Folder structure includes
values
values-es
values-fr
values-sw600dp

values has the mdpi values stored in the dimens.xml file all done in dp and sp.
dimens.xml:

(NOTE*) Whenever I tried to add the xml snippet from the dimens.xml it kept formatting it funny and removing all the dimen name= stuff and just lists out the dp and sp used in it. Not sure why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="center_text_margin_right">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_row_top_padding">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_row_bottom_padding">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_number_text_size">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_left_margin_from_answer_number">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_text_size">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_points_right_margin">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_points_left_margin">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_number_left_margin">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="center_text_size">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="center_text_margin_left">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="center_text_margin_right">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_title_height">28dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="round_circle_margin_left">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="round_circle_height">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="round_circle_width">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="total_score_right_margin">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="total_score_left_margin">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="score_text_size">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="trivia_logo_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="trivia_logo_width">84dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="trivia_logo_margin_left">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_margin_left">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_margin_right">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_top_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_margin_bottom">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_text_size">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fun_fact_margin_bottom">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fun_fact_text_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_row_height">25dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

If I create a values-hdpi folder with this file
dimens.xml

30.00dp
    10.50dp
    10.50dp
    18.00dp
    27.00dp
    18.00dp
    30.00dp
    27.00dp
    90.00dp
    18.00dp
    30.00dp
    30.00dp
    42.00dp
    9.00dp
    9.00dp
    9.00dp
    39.00dp
    7.50dp
    18.00dp
    37.50dp
    126.00dp
    8dp
    39.00dp
    39.00dp
    22.50dp
    30.00dp
    18.00dp
    150.00dp
    18.00dp
    37.50dp

everything will work fine

The values-es and values-fr are just folders containing strings.xml NO dimens in there. I reference all throughout my layout xml files with @dimen/answer_row_height for example.

As I stated before it works perfectly if I drop in the values-hdpi with a scaled dimens.xml file in it, but if I remove it Android does not scale it. Has anyone hit this before or know what i'm screwing up?

Comment: Please post your dimens.xml from values and values-sw600dp

Comment: Trimmed to fit comment limit    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="center_text_margin_right">40.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_row_top_padding">14.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_row_bottom_padding">14.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_number_text_size">24.00sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_left_margin_from_answer_number">36.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_text_size">24.00sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_points_right_margin">40.00dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_points_left_margin">36.00dp</dimen>
</resources>

Comment: How are you accessing those `dimens.xml` values?

Comment: An SGS4 in landscape might hit the sw600dp resource. Can you confirm it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values will not be automatically scaled, only drawables will be.

It's up to you to define all the alternative resources (values included) that your app will need, the framework cannot and will not make those decisions for you.

Comment: Density-independent pixel (dp)
A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160).

Comment: For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  Is this not correct, or am I misunderstanding it. I have other project samples that only have these two directories for values and values-sw600dp and are scaling everywhere just fine. I'm starting to think it may be relevent to IntelliJ build process maybe.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What exactly do you mean by "scaling the dimens.xml file in values-hdpi", though? It sounds to me like you're changing the actual `dp` values to achieve a situation where the app scales proportionally to the screen size (instead of leaving more whitespace on a larger screen). I wouldn't blame IntelliJ just yet (unless you're using lots of Android libraries with complicated dependencies).

Comment: So for example the specs that I have been given show a row height of 25dp on a medium density screen and text height of 12sp. I know that to go to hdpi it is a 1.5 multiplier which I thought Android handles for you when it recognizes that your device is hdpi. However, it seems the only way to get it to behave properly is to create a values-hdpi folder and a second dimens.xml with the scaled values for hdpi in it already. I didn't think I had to do this... From my understanding Android OS handles scaling of densities in the values directory to the device density assuming mdpi starting point.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the relationship between density and on-screen size. Android will indeed convert that `25dp` to `37px` on hdpi (and keep it as `25px` on mdpi) but what this will produce is the same on-screen size, regardless of the difference between the screens' sizes. It compensates for **density** and it sounds to me like you expect it to compensate for **screen size** too.

Comment: Right on, @Delyan. It appears the OP is confusing terms a bit here.

Comment: I don't think that's it.... If I put the 37dp in dimens.xml in values-hdpi and 25dp in values dimens.xml everything looks consistently the same across screens the way I would expect. However, if I do not make the dimens.xml inside of the values-hdpi with the 37dp value it will still use the 25dp value and appear smaller on the SGS3 and SGS4 then it does if I had provided the values. i do not want it to increase the size. I want it to look the same across devices, but right now it only looks good on mdpi devices, when I use an hdpi device it looks tiny.

Comment: What devices are you testing between?

Comment: SGS3, SGS4, Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, and an older HTC. I have plenty of other devices as well, but I'm just noticing that it does not provide the 1.5 scaled ratio to px for the hdpi device. I've spent days on this :(. It only works if i provide all the ratio scaled dp as indicated in the documentation with ldpi 0.75, mdpi 1.0, hdpi 1.5 and xhdpi 2.0. If I use that math and scale the dp of each respective density directory based on those values, it works great. This is what I'm trying to avoid though as Android is supposed to handle this for you.

Comment: I am fairly new at scaling though so bare with me as my knowledge on screen support is in it's infancy stages right now, but I feel like i understand it, but I obviously do not or it would be working. lol.

Comment: I can guarantee you that it *is* scaling up the `dp` values. You can verify that by dumping the pixel values with `getWidth()`/`getHeight()` on different devices.
Galaxy Tab 2 is mdpi, SGS{3,4} are xhdpi and the HTC is an unknown. Let's take the Tab 2 and SGS4. The Tab has a 149ppi screen, while the SGS4 has a 441ppi screen. 10dp in values/dimens.xml would be 10px on the Tab 2 and 20px on the SGS4. However, due to the different sizes, that's 0.067in on the Tab2 and 0.0454in on the SGS4. Clearly different sizes, though the density has been taken into account.

Comment: Dimension resources *can* be specified in `mm` and `in`, which should take care of actual screen size conversion but you really should not design your app in those units.

Comment: Ok so I confirmed. When I do a getHeight and getWidth as well as txtBox.getTextSize() they are using all the mdpi provided values. But if I do the int size = a.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK; it is definitely hdpi so it doesn't make sense that it is using the mdpi values that are in the dimens.xml file

Comment: `screenLayout` *has nothing to do with density*. It has everything to do with screen size, though (actual physical size, measured in inches). The sizes are explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range). You can get the density with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yhdam13ba1qyyr/testscaleapp.zip Please see demo project. Run this on a hdpi device and you will see that everything rendors based on the mdpi values in the dimens.xml file. Maybe this will show what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I would expect this to show 45, 120, and 18, but instead it shows 30, 80, 12. Maybe this is just my misunderstanding of how this works....

Comment: It *is* your misunderstanding. I haven't run it but the code is printing out `dp`s. They are *density-independent*; you're changing the density between devices, but that won't change them. The pixel quantity changes but the `dp`s do not, which is what makes them useful! I'm not entirely sure how to explain this better, other than resort to the docs. I really encourage you to read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) top to bottom to figure out what's going on. The screenshots part is especially useful but do read the whole thing.

Comment: Hi Deylan, lol I have read that doc more times then you can imagine. You are definitely correct. I was misunderstanding the relationship. I thought the dp scales based on density differences, but that is not the case. The dp remains the same, it is the px that scales. I understand now. Wow that one took me a while, I feel a little slow right about now. Thanks for all the help. The design spec-ed to me was so tiny that I thought for sure things weren't scaling, but actually the ux team just supplied really tiny values and need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the documentation Android OS will assume your dimens.xml
>   is created for mdpi and scale accordingly for hdpi, xhdpi, etc...

That is incorrect. Whatever you put in `dimens.xml` is going to be used as is, if the dimensions are in pixels (`px`). You'll need to put them in density-independent-pixels (`dp`) to make them scale. `dimens.xml` should not be based on resolution but on screen size. You might have a `dimens.xml` in `values` and in `values-large`, specifying different spacing, or even different font-sizes for larger screens.

You should *not* have a `dimens.xml` in `values` and `values-hdpi`, because the `dp` unit already takes care of density-scaling.

Based on the comments you left in various places, it appears that you are not accessing the dimensions resources correctly. You should be using something like:

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen. round_circle_height );
```

if retrieving values from code, or

```
@dimen/round_circle_height
```

if referencing from xml.

Comment: I have only used dp and sp for all values in hopes of it scaling, but that is not working. I also do not have a values-large. I only have a values and a values-sw600dp. I'm testing on an SGS3 an SGS4 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. The Tab 2 is grabbing densitiy values from the values-sw600 and the phones are grabbing values from the values folder using the dp values listed in the xml rather then scaling to hdpi which they are meant to be.

Comment: Define "scaling to hdpi which they are meant to be." They are *not* "meant" to "scale." The idea of `dp` values is that a 40x40dp button will *always* be 1/4" square, regardless of tablet resolution. This may translate to 40x40 pixels on mdpi, or it may be a button of 80x80 pixels on xhdpi. Are you expecting the UI elements to get scaled up for larger screens?

Comment: No....I'm probably confusing with my wording. I want the layout to look the same across all devices. NOT get bigger. I want consistent sizing. Right now the design only looks good on mdpi devices. It looks tiny on hdpi devices unless I supply the directory for values-hdpi with a scaled dimens.xml file at the 1.5 ratio. If I supply that scaled version of the dimens.xml it looks fine, otherwise it does not scale the px based on the densities provided at the mdpi level

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it all from xml just as you showed it abov   <EditText android:id="@+id/txtId"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/test_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/test_height"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/test_padding"
            android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:textSize="@dimen/score_text_size"
            android:text="1"
            android:background="@drawable/liv_shape_black_rectangle"
            android:hint="ID" />

Comment: I just added those test values to confirm whether or not it was scaling on the first screen and it is definitely not scaling the pxs based on the density provided and density independent pixels specified

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yhdam13ba1qyyr/testscaleapp.zip Please see demo project. Run this on a hdpi device and you will see that everything rendors based on the mdpi values in the dimens.xml file. Maybe this will show what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I think I figured it out finally with your direction. I believe the dp does not change from device to device, but the translation of that dp to px is what differs. Therefore the px was different from device to device, but the dp was the same. This was the confusing part for me. I was thinking the dp scales, when in fact only the px scales based on the device density and the dp value supplied in the dimens.xml file. i think I am fine now. Thanks so much for all the help and direction

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Yes, `dp` or `dip` means density **independent** pixels, as I stated in my response to your first comment, and @Delyan stated multiple times as well. Once you get the hang of it, Android's handling of hardware variants is quite a timesaver.